# Nextjs window object undefined in _document.tsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

**My Current Setup**

I have a Google Tag Manager script tag placed in the `_document.tsx` file nested under the `<Head>` component:

```
class MyDocument extends Document {

  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head>
          <script
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
              __html: `<!-- Google Tag Manager -->`,
            }}
          />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <noscript
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
              __html: `<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->`,
            }}
          />
          <style
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
              __html: (this.props as any).globalStyles,
            }}
          ></style>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    )
  }
}
```

**My Goal**

We have certain pages set up that are meant for international customers, and those pages all have a "-INTL" at the end of the url (for example: `https://www.mystore.com/product--INTL`).

My goal is to have Google Tag Manager **NOT** render if it is an international link, which contains the "--INTL" string in the URL.

Ideally, I want to wrap the entire Google Tag Manager script into its own component, then conditionally render that based on the URL of the page.

**Ideal Setup that doesn't work**

GTM Component Code:

```
class GTMComponent extends React.Component {
    let currentUrl;
    
    componentDidMount(){

        if(typeof window !== "undefined"){
            currentUrl = window.location.href; 
        }
    }

    render(){

           if(!currentUrl.contains("--INTL")){
               return (
                   <script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: `<!-- 
                   Google Tag Manager Script -->`}}/>
                )
            }
            else {
             return (
              <></>
             )
            }
    }
}

export default GTMComponent
```

_document.tsx file with GTMComponent:

```
import GTMComponent from '@components/common/GTMComponent'

class MyDocument extends Document {
    

    render(){
        return(
            <HTML>
                <Head>
                    <GTMComponent/>
                </Head>
                <body>
                {/* body code */}
                </body>
            </HTML>    
        )
    }
}

export default MyDocument
```

**My Problem**

I want to be able to access the `window` object, but due to Server Side Rendering, the `window` object is never defined.

Additionally, I can't use `useEffect` since `_document.tsx` is a class-based component, and I weirdly can't get `componentDidMount` to work either.

Comment: Since you're trying to utilize the window, I'd recommend the [_app.js page](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app). This approach of putting it in the _app page seems to reflect their [with-google-tag-manager example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-google-tag-manager).

Comment: `_document` runs on the server-side only, you can't execute operations that depend on `window` from there. As already suggested, move the logic to `_app`.